# Stored procedures delivering JSON to Angular

Tags: json, sql-server, angular

We are developing a new browser-based UI for our enterprise-wide system in Angular.js with the Infragistics toolset. ASP.NET Core Web API is the transport layer to pass JSON between the UI and the database.

We have recently begun a project with many hierarchical grids in the UI which is making hand coding the SQL Server stored procedures to return the JSON very complicated and inefficient.

We are looking for a generic method of coding the stored procedures or a tool which can generate the stored procedure from a mapping between the UI and the database, including the need to pass in parameters to the stored procedure.

Any suggestions? Gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for handling data mapping and business logic. One thing I would like to point out is that you want to keep your layers dedicated to their purpose. You want your database to deliver data, your backend to process the data and apply the business logic and your frontend to display the prepared data.

Now I am not sure what your purpose your database procedures serve but you can definitely look into [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/). It allows you to easily make calls to your database, map your models and set up database migrations. It also has a functionality of [calling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-database-sqlquery-1(system-string-system-object())) your database procedures and passing the parameters (like many alternatives out there).